# Call each item when multiple selector perform in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, multipleselection

I want to set each of the checkbox's `.parent("span").prop("title")` to their `.parent("span").parent("td").parent("tr")`'s title. Because of jQuery iteratively perform when there are multiple elements, can't I do something like this without a loop?

```
$(":checkbox").parent("span").parent("td").parent("tr").prop("title", $(this).parent("span").prop("title"));
```

Rendered in browser something like this.

```
<tr class="GridRow_Default" id="ctl00_body_grdTime_ctl00__2">
    <td align="center">
        <span title="Regularizable">
            <input id="ctl00_body_grdTime_ctl00_ctl07_chkSub" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$body$grdTime$ctl00$ctl07$chkSub">
        </span>
    </td>       
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

> can't I do something like this without a loop?

**NO.** To get the current elements reference, you've to iterate over the elements.

You can use [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over all checkboxes.

```
$(':checkbox').each(function () {
    // `$(this)` here is the current checkbox

    $(this)
        .closest('tr') // Get closest ancestor `<tr>`
        .attr('title', $(this).parent().attr('title')); // Set attribute value of `title` to that of the `parent`
});
```

Comment: I think OP wants to achieve this without using loop. `can n't I do something like this without a loop?`

Comment: @RinoRaj Yes, but that's not possible. I've added description.

Comment: @RayonDabre From jQuery source, `prop` and `attr` setters uses `access()`. Here's how `jQuery.fn.extend( {
 prop: function( name, value ) {
  return access( this, jQuery.prop, name, value, arguments.length > 1 );
 },` and `access` iterates over elements, `var access = function( elems, fn, key, value, chainable, emptyGet, raw ) { ...... if ( fn ) {
       for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
        fn(
         elems[ i ],
         key,
         raw ? value : value.call( elems[ i ], i, fn( elems[ i ], key ) )
        );
       }
      }`

Comment: @Tushar, Yes, You are [right](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.prop)

Comment: @Tushar This one works fine! See `Derek's` answer with call back function.. it works too...

Comment: @Nishantha yes, but that is using two loops. One to get the `<tr>`s having checkbox inside them and then to get the `title` attribute.

Comment: @Tushar that's  true.

Comment: @Nishantha If your problem is solved, please accept the answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Use filter() to get just the TRs with SPAN which contain an INPUT:CHECKBOX element, and set the value of the title property of the SPAN to the TR.

```
$('tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('span > :checkbox').length; 
}).prop('title', function() { return $(this).find('span').eq(0).prop('title'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) , [`.prop(function(propertyName, function)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function) , [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest)

```
$("span:has(:checkbox)").prop("title", function(index, prop) {
  return $(this).closest("tr").prop("title");
})
```